# How to return all matches in mysql where value occurs in string at position n?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, position, substring, where-clause

Im looking to run a query in phpmyadmin (mysql) that wil check a table for a specific value at a specific postion in a string, i'm new to mysql and this is what i've tried but there's a syntax issue. I'm looking to find the value "1" at position 5 and display all those users that possess this.

```
SELECT* 
FROM`user` 
WHERE`options`LOCATE(`options`,1,5) 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

regards,
Silo

Comment: Additional examples:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/9201082/1175253

Comment: @Silo the reason you had a syntax issue, coz the way you use `Locate` has a little syntax miss-arrangements :) [Check this out](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-locate-function.php)

Comment: @bonCodigo i see, like i said im new to queries like this and previous ones i've built similar you normally declare the table before and after the parenthesis like REPLACE, thanks for the heads up, stuff like this helps me learn whats going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Locate is for finding a value ANYWHERE in a string. You want a specific location only, so use [`substr()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//string-functions.html#function_substr) instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user
WHERE substr(options, 5, 1) = '1'
```

Comment: Brilliant, easy when you know how :)

Comment: @Marc B according to the reference `Locate' can find a 'string' at a particular position where position is the starting point :) Please share if you think there's a flaw or a drawback.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
SELECT* 
FROM`user` 
WHERE options LIKE '____1%'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Another ;)

```
SELECT * 
FROM user
WHERE instr(options, '1') = 5
```

**Duh** .. Well won't work since it only returns the first occurnace :$ But CHECK the reference,

- [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd5bc/3) using `Locate()`

Sample data:

```
COL1    COL2
G11     112
G11-1   0
G11-2   2
G12-2   111
```

Query1:

```
-- to check on varchar columns
SELECT * 
FROM tablex
where locate('1',col1,5)
;
```

Results on varchar:

```
COL1    COL2
G11-1   0
```

Query 2:

```
-- to check on int columns
SELECT * 
FROM tablex
where locate(1,col2,2)
;
```

Results on int:

```
COL1    COL2
G11     112
G12-2   111
```

Comment: No thank you Silo :( coz `instr` is not going to work. `Substr` is the best catch. However your `Locate` seems to work in the refernce given. If curious please take a look. And +1 for @Marc B

Comment: @bonCondigo, i appreciate your effort but all that went wayyyyy over my head :)

Comment: @Silo then vote up ;) if you think it makes sense. And the function (`locate`) you initially choose is not so bad :)